# How to bind Command In listview MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I would like when i click on my item, this item can execute my command

View :

```
<Page
x:Class="p1.View.listTest"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:p1.View"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
DataContext="{Binding SecondPageInstance, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"  Margin="0,0,0,-70">
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeView}" Content="ReturnButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,554,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding ChangeView}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="278" Margin="19,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="594">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeView}" Content="Change View"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
 </Grid>
</page>
```

ViewModel :

```
public RelayCommand ChangeView{ get; private set; }

public VM_liste(INavigationService navigationService)
{
     _navigationService = navigationService;
     ChangeView= new RelayCommand(_ChangeView);
}

private void _ChangeView()
{
     _navigationService.GoBack();
}
```

But i click, on my selectedItem Or on the button. There is Nothing.
However if i click on my ReturnButton It's working...

Comment: I don't see where you declared view model code but in data template the context is the item (not the list or the outer model). Is it where your command is placed? If not then just fix the binding

Comment: I work with ViewModelLocator. I bind my DataContext with my ViewModel, in my ViewModelLocator.
I have seen, what we can attache an event but i know how do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need it like this with the DataContext set to a ListViewModel Instance.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangeView1}" Content="ReturnButton"/> 
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding ChangeView2}" Content="Change View"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And your ViewModels:

```
public class ListViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<ListItemViewModel> Items => ...;
    public RelayCommand ChangeView1 => ...;
}

public class ListItemViewModel {
    public string Name => ...;
    public RelayCommand ChangeView2 => ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: You can try out this example.

```
<DataTemplate>
          <Button
              Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=DataContext.OpenItemCommand}">
          </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```